# Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined when trying to add token inside stateChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My objective is to to send a token as Authorization header to each of the service calls in my application.

Here is my code

```
'use strict';

var properties = {};

angular.module('nbaportalUi', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize',
  'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'uiSwitch'])
   .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$window', '$cookies', function ($rootScope, $state, $window, $cookies, $http) {

       $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {



           $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer carmeloanthony' ;


       });
  }])


  .config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

   $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/home');

    // note the 'abstract:true' state below - it can not get activated
    // it is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'
      })
       .state('app.overview', {
        url: '/overview',
        templateUrl: 'app/overview/summary.html',
        controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
      })
      .state('loginPage', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .state('errorPage', {
        url: '/error404',
        templateUrl: 'app/404.html'
      });


  })
  .constant('ENV', {
    'name': 'dev',
    'apiEndpoint': 'https://api.blah.com/nba/v1/team/' 
  })
;
```

I am inserting `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer carmeloanthony' ;` inside $stateChangeStart because it is called every time.

However when i attempt to this i get an error saying

```
angular.js:11706 TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at index.js:43
```

This error is refering to the following line of code ->  `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer carmeloanthony' ;`

However when i try to add the token as authorization adder outside stateChangeStart as follows it works:

```
'use strict';

var properties = {};

angular.module('nbaportalUi', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize',
  'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'uiSwitch'])
   .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$window', '$cookies', function ($rootScope, $state, $window, $cookies) {

       $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {






       });
  }])


  .config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

     $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/home');

    // note the 'abstract:true' state below - it can not get activated
    // it is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'
      })
       .state('app.overview', {
        url: '/overview',
        templateUrl: 'app/overview/summary.html',
        controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
      })
      .state('loginPage', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .state('errorPage', {
        url: '/error404',
        templateUrl: 'app/404.html'
      });


  })
  .constant('ENV', {
    'name': 'dev',
    'apiEndpoint': 'https://api.blah.com/nba/v1/team/' 
  })
;

angular.module('nbaportalUi').run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer carmeloanthony' ;

});
```

I would prefer to get my first approach working. I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the `$http` service as following (your forgot to put in the array) :

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$window', '$cookies','$http', function ($rootScope, $state, $window, $cookies, $http) {
```